# How to render web kit contents on a video in Android?

Tags: android, video, webview, webkit, overlay

Hi I am working an app where my requirement is to  to render web kit contents on a Video in Android ..like displaying adds on a video. My research do far has revealed that web-view control uses web kit and it can render the same.I am trying a technique like including video view layout in web view to achieve my target. I am able to show web-view contents over video being played in the back ground however I am not able to make web view contents transparent so that it does not block the video...Is there any way I can achieve this  and make web view and its contents transparent or overlay them on video in back ground. Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out solution myself. To render web kit contents use Web view control that uses web  kit and to make it transparent or give it an overlay effect we can use set Alpha property of the same. Hope it might help some one.